# Pass Data using Closures

Tags: ios, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

I know that there are multiple approaches to pass data back from one controller to another like `Delegates, NSNotifications`. I am using another way using `Closures` to pass data data back. I just want to know is it safe way how I pass any data using blocks like below or should I avoid this approach.

**First ViewController (where I make object of Second ViewController)**

```
 @IBAction func push(sender: UIButton) {
        let v2Obj = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("v2ViewController") as! v2ViewController

        v2Obj.completionBlock = {(dataReturned) -> ()in
            //Data is returned **Do anything with it **

            print(dataReturned)

        }
        navigationController?.pushViewController(v2Obj, animated: true)

    }
```

**Second ViewController (where data is passed back to First VC)**

```
import UIKit
typealias v2CB = (infoToReturn :NSString) ->()
class v2ViewController: UIViewController {

    var completionBlock:v2CB?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func returnFirstValue(sender: UIButton) {

        guard let cb = completionBlock else {return}

        cb(infoToReturn: returnFirstValue)

    }
    @IBAction func returnSecondValue(sender: UIButton) {

        guard let cb = completionBlock else {return}

        cb(infoToReturn: returnSecondValue)

    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with this approach but do take care to understand how your closures capture values and can create retain cycles.

Comment: Yes retain cycle should be taken care

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a very good and reasonable approach and much better than notifications.

Looking at the *evolution* of Cocoa API you will notice that Apple has replaced more and more delegate API with blocks / closures over the years.

Comment: One thing more I want to know, The way how I pass multiple different values back is safe way or should i pass data back using methods that contains block as a parameter.

Comment: It's perfectly fine. That's one of the benefits of closures.

Comment: Thanks man!! You really lifted off confusion off my sholuders

Comment: is there an objective c equivalent?

Comment: @vnchopra Yes, blocks exist in Objective-C since macOS 10.6 Snow Leopard.

Comment: @vadian i mean is there a block equivalent for passing data back from the second view controller to the first?

Comment: Actually it's the same pattern. Closures in Swift are Blocks in Objective-C